# How can I enable lexical binding for Elisp code in org-mode?

Tags: org-babel, lexical-binding

I have the following code:

```
#+begin_src elisp
(setq lexical-binding t)
(let ((a 1))                            ; binding (1)
  (let ((f (lambda () (print a))))
    (let ((a 2))                        ; binding (2)
      (funcall f)))) ; result: 2
#+end_src
```

Since I set `lexical-binding` to `t`, lexical bindings should be used instead of dynamic bindings. So I think the result of the above should be `1`. But the result is `2`. It's as if Emacs is still using dynamic bindings. Why? How can I make it use lexical bindings?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn on the header `:lexical`, e.g.,

```
#+begin_src elisp :lexical t :results pp
(lambda ())
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: (closure
:  (t)
:  nil)
```

You can also use `#+PROPERTY: header-args:elisp :lexical t` to turn it on for the whole org file. Or change `org-babel-default-header-args:emacs-lisp` to turn it on globally.

`(setq lexical-binding t)` in the code does not work since it's too late, the scope (dynamic or lexical) is already decided BEFORE any of your code runs, hence to turn on lexical-binding, Emacs requires a special comment, which can be added via

```
M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line lexical-binding t
```

Comment: I’m interested to know how to make this work for elisp code that is tangled from org files. I have an org file that tangles to multiple elisp files, and the org file has the `#+PROPERTY` line set as you specified; but, none of the resulting elisp files contain the special `lexical-binding: t;` comment, nor are lambdas converted to closures or anything like that. Any ideas?